# A single-word synonym for the phrasal verb "to look in(to)" used literally?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrasal-verbs

I am seeking a single-word transitive verb that is a synonym of the phrasal verb "to look in" or "to look into", used literally (as in "to look in the mirror") rather than metaphorically (to mean "investigate").

Example:

> A woman walked in and _____ the mirror.

Comment: In the phrases look **into/in the mirror** or look **in/into the room**, look is a single word.

Comment: And in those phrases, _in_ is used metaphorically, not literally. There is no inside to a mirror.

Comment: You can look into a jar or a pot or a hole or a machine. They're all three-dimensional and concave.

Comment: @JohnLawler I dunno really: "When you place an object in front of a mirror, you see an image of the same object in the mirror". https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/mirrors///But hey, what do I know? In any case, the into/in are part of a prepositional phrase.

Comment: Oh, _in_ is the preposition we use for images -- _in the picture_ -- beyond doubt. But it's not literal, because there's no inside. We see a 2-D image of a 3-D scene as if it were real; but that's what metaphor is all about. If the OP has a different concept in mind, they didn't give any examples of it.

Comment: We do say the image was reflected in the mirror. So, I can look at the mirror and see my reflection in it.  I am not sure what *in*  as literal actually means. If I say "this is understood in the sense of x" is that a metaphor? Isn't all language ultimately a fiction that cannot account for the real? It's all approximate....

Comment: Is your native language French or some other Romance language? If so, you need to accept  how languages differ. You can’t do it!

Comment: @David Who exactly are you talking to?

Comment: @Lambie — The poster, obviously. That's who comments are for unless an @ handle is specified. I suppose it neither asks for clarification or suggest improvements, so it might be regarded as inappropriate for a comment. I suppose I could have asked him why.

Comment: @David I guess I didn't understand your comment. It's just that some people here have tried to say I am not an English speaker. Imagine that. So, it has made me paranoid. :)

Comment: @Lambie No problem. The poster may not, in fact, be a non-native speaker, but I always find it strange when people expect equivalent constructions in different languages, especially when the dictionaries don’t provide anything. Perhaps it’s for verse or terse prose à la Mickey Spillane “The dame walked in and ‘scanned’ the mirror.” But stop me before I get carried away.

Comment: @David Frankly, I think a few circuits could be missing. :)

Comment: @Lambie - Did something make you think I believed "look" was zero or two or more words rather than one word?

Comment: @ruffle You can flag irrelevant comments but you need to respect that this question has answers by not editing your post to delete all its content.

Comment: "I am seeking a single-word transitive verb that is a synonym of the phrasal verb "to look in" or "to look into", used literally": the single word is **look**. "in the mirror" here is not phrasal. It is part of a prepositional phrase.

Comment: There is probably no answer here. When the woman walks into the room, the focus of her thought could be the mirror itself (“what a nicely-made frame”) or the reflection in the mirror (“I wish I’d worn a different hat”). The use of **at** or **in** or **into** helps convey the direction of her thought.  The only single-word expression I can think of is: “she *considered* the mirror”.  Either that or *regarded*.

Comment: Yes, extending what John says, 'Police looked into the affair' uses the opaque (!) metaphor, 'She looked into the mirror' uses the transparent metaphor (dare one say it's a virtual image) and 'She looked into the room' uses the literal usage and a V + PP structure. One could argue about the structure of 'She looked into the mirror'. Is the metaphor the use of this 'look into' or just this 'into'?

Answer (score 1):

If you would accept a preposition, I suggest *peer into*. The only single word I can come up with is

**regard** (v.)

> To look at [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regard)

> Gaze at steadily in a specified fashion. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/Gaze)

> To look at attentively; observe closely
>
> *He **regarded** the delicate
> lines of her profile* (Thomas Hardy). [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=regard)

---

> Fiona **regarded the mirror** suspiciously. "You may have noticed this
> wart," she said, touching one at random. [David Langford; *He Do the
> Time Police in Different Voices*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22regarded%20the%20mirror%22) (2003)

> Allison **regarded the mirror** again and pushed the bangs back for a
> second, then brushed them down into place. [Phyllis Whitney; *The
> Trembling Hills*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Trembling_Hills/TLU3DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22regarded%20the%20mirror%22&pg=PT83&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> I **regarded the mirror**. Funny, vampires weren't supposed to cast
> reflections, were they?  [Jack Stevens; *Dark Matter*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dark_Master/Gk0wEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22regarded%20the%20mirror%22&pg=PT123&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> I **regarded** the contents of the cup in my hand reluctantly and then
> welcomed its warmth into my mouth. [Tracey Newman; *Illusion*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Illusion/rHohDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I%20regarded%20the%20contents%22&pg=PT124&printsec=frontcover)
> (2016)

> She looked me up and down without a flicker of interest and I
> **regarded** her carefully in return. [Francis Knight; *Fade to Black*](https://6rKEdD1dInEC) (2013)

> But at length, as the labor drew nearer to its conclusion, there were
> admitted none into the turret; for the painter had grown wild with the
> ardor of his work, and turned his eyes from canvas merely, even to
> **regard** the countenance of his wife. [Edgar Allen Poe; *The Oval Portrait*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2147/2147-h/2147-h.htm)

Comment: Lot of bad writing around. I wouldn’t use regard, myself, but if I did I would regard myself, not the mirror.

Answer (score 0):

The alternatives I came up with are the following:

"She walked in and saw/glimpsed herself in the mirror."

"in" is still present in the prepositional phrase, but it's separated from the verb by the direct object, so maybe this will suffice.

Comment: glimpsed herself is not a single word.

Answer (score -1):

*Looked/gazed into* seems the simplest way to distinguish the image from the glass itself, but the phrase **inspected the mirror** might work as a replacement for *looked at her image in the mirror*.

Or, leaving the mirror implied, **inspected her reflection**.

Answer (score -1):

You're not going to get a common word but you can use **introspect** as a transitive verb with the sense "To look into": the OED says this is "rare" and "usually with the mind" (i.e. metaphorically) but it does not exclude literal use. Just be aware that you are using it in an unusual way if you say "she introspected the mirror". Unlike some alternatives this is not ambiguous. It would be suitable in some forms of writing (maybe a historical novel) but not others (informal message).

The OED's examples are metaphorical or ambiguous but they show the syntax. A 19th century example is "The records of the intellect introspecting human nature cannot evince a perfect understanding." Or 18th century: "look into it, there is nothing; so beware they do not introspect you."

Otherwise, the far better option is to use a phrasal verb or preposition. (The verb *inspect* formerly meant to look into, but now "inspect the mirror" would universally be taken to mean examine the mirror, not look into it.)

References:

"introspect, v.". OED Online. March 2022. Oxford University Press. (accessed March 26, 2022).

"inspect, v.". OED Online. March 2022. Oxford University Press. (accessed March 26, 2022)